# In Google sheets I have a form in my sidebar that is not submitting the data. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to coding and I wanted to make data entry more uniform in my worplace. And so I have been trying to create a html form in a sidebar and submit the resulting data to a speadsheet.
I have my form and my sidebar working but no matter what I try or which tutorial I follow I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get the data from the html form to my spreadsheet.

Here is the .gs

```js
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
     .createMenu('Menu CFC')
     .addItem('Ajout','showSidebar')
     .addToUi();
  showSidebar();
}

function showSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('menuCFC')
  .setTitle('Mon menu CFC')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showSidebar(html);
}

function formCFCSubmit(form_data){
  var sheet = spreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Feuille 1');

  sheet.([form_data.nom,form_data.numéro])
}
```

and here is a simplified version of my html form for testing purpose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
 </head>
  <body>

   <form name="formAjoutCFC">
      <div class ="block form-group">
      <label for="Nom">Nom</label>
      <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" placeholder="Nom" required>
      </div>

      <div class ="block form-group">
      <label for="Numéro">Numéro</label>
      <input type="text" name="numéro" id="numéro" placeholder="Numéro" required>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
      <button type="submit" class="action">Valider</button>
      </div>

      <div calss="block">
      <input type="reset">
      </div>
   </form>
   <script>
    document.querySelector("#formAjoutCFC").addEventListener("submit", //not sure about the #
    function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();    
    google.script.run.formCFCSubmit(this);    
    );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be welcome as I'm out of my depth at the moment ^^

Comment: [Mcve]. If there's a problem,  describe the problem: provide error quotes and so forth. Read [mcve] and [ask]. Your question and title say nothing about the problem.

Comment: @Lugh since you are new here check out [some guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all right @Lugh, very close to your goal indeed. But you need to take care of some things:

Your `showSideBar` function is alright too.

#### On your `formCFCSubmit(form_data)` you have errors:

1. The class you want to call from is `SpreadsheetApp` not `(s)preadsheetApp`.
2. `sheet.([form_data.nom,form_data.numéro])` is not an existing method.

```js
// For testing purposes, you can paste the data in ranges "A1" and "B1" for example:
function formCFCSubmit(form_data){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Feuille 1');
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(form_data.nom);
  sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(form_data.numero); 
  // Notice accent removed from numero! 
  // Putting accents in code will give you headaches sooner than later...
}
```

#### On your `menuCFC.html`:

Here is where most of your trouble is coming from...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Notice 'id'! That's what the # in the query selector is referencing. Not name -->
    <form id="formAjoutCFC"> 
        <div class="block form-group">
            <label for="Nom">Nom</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" placeholder="Nom" required>
        </div>
        <div class="block form-group">
            <label for="Numero">Numéro</label>
            <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Numéro" required>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <button type="submit" class="action">Valider</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <input type="reset">
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#formAjoutCFC")
            .addEventListener(
                "submit",
                function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    google.script.run.formCFCSubmit(this);
                }
            );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the script in your sidebar, can get the form by id, and when submitted execute the `formCFCSubmit` function that does what you want it to with `form_data`.

Keep on coding!

---

**Notes:**

- You should read official documentation now that you are into coding.
- Read about the [`SpreadsheetsApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class from Apps Script's Spreadsheet service to find out which functions you can use to tailor to your need.

Comment: Thank you for you well thought out answer to my query. Ill get back to working on it and see how I do :).

Comment: So I tried your methode since it make a whole more sense (minus removing the `showSidebar` in the `onOpen` function since it make the sidebar popup upon opening the document). But after trying a few thing it seems lt still wont stop giving me an error. Stating that the `(form_data.X)` cannot be read because it's undefined which seems weird.

Comment: ok, it seems you may be referencing the variable before assigning a value to it. Post another question, with the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much with basic stuff T_T. So I tried  this`function doGet(e){
  var nom = e.parameter.nom
  var numero = e.parameter.numero
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(nom)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(numero)
  }` to fish the relevent information from the html file in the hope of feedinding it to my formCFCSubmit

Comment: Since `function formCFCSubmit(form_data){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Feuille 1');
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(form_data.nom);  sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(form_data.numero); 
}` doesn't seem to be able to reference the information from the html maybe an issue with the way i'm using `google.script.run.`